# Splashscreen displaying ionic logo vs my splashscreen on launch

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

So to my knowledge, i have done everything right, but the ionic logo is still flashing up very briefly on the app launch rather than my splash-screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pNEo.jpg

See the link above for a gif on what my app is doing.

Currently i have removed the iOS platform, ran `sudo ionic cordova resources generate` multiple times and checked all the .xcodeproj file for traces of the original ionic logo, but can't seem to find any anywhere.

If anyone has any knowledge to why the app is doing this, it would be much appriciated.

For parts of the config.xml that matter, see:

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

which all came as default when creating the blank template.

My Resources folder file structure is as follows:

[image: Resources Page Image]

- Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the iOS 11.4 beta seems to be at fault. Tried and tested on the simulator and a co-workers iPhone X and the problem seems to have been resolved. Just not working on my personal iDevice. Will monitor in future beta versions to see if it is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove all resources from the folder. Then run

```
sudo ionic cordova resources ios
```

that will generate the files back again. If that didn't generate the resources use

```
sudo ionic cordova resources ios -f
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Kirubel. Tried the -f method and it's still showing the ionic splashscreen temporarily. I've done 2 apps before which are on the app store with the exact same methods which worked perfectly. I just can't understand why it is showing up on this instance.

Comment: Have you deleted the resources from the folder first? I've been in the same situation. That's how I fix the issue.

Comment: Deleted the iOS folder from within the resources folder then re-ran. Haven't deleted the resources folder though if that's what you mean?

Comment: You should delete the resources folder that was the issue. Then run the code again. It'll work like a charm.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Still flashing up with the ionic splashscreen for about .5 of a second before displaying my splashscreen. This is after deleting the resource folder and going from there. Looking into the xcassets folder it seems like the resources fails to generate the 'Default-2436h' resource, so i'm going to try adding this manually and the go from there.

Comment: Just tested on the simulators and it's working fine. Just wondering if it is a problem with the iOS beta which is running on my iPhone X.